# The word to describe the easier of two hard things

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I want a word that can replace the following sentence or make it more concise. I have two things A and B, and both of them are really hard to do. However, A is easier to do than B, but it's not doable in an easy way. Assume B is "going to Nipton" and A is "going to Mars". I'm looking for a word that conveys this meaning that can replace the X in:

"A is X than B"

X: both of them are really hard, but after a long time, we can do A before B.

**Edit**: a useful comment down there says I need a word that says:

"A is X than B"

where X: less hard to do.

Comment: You're going at it backwards. You don't want to say A is *more* X than B which implies that both are X in some degree: you want to say it's ***less*** X than B--less difficult or impracticable or feasible or whatever.

Comment: @StoneyB you're absolutely right. I edited the question. I think I answered my question though. However, I'm curious to know if there is a word that satisfies the original question.

Comment: Do not say "less harder" to do. Simply say "easier" to do. (Just as you did at the start of your question.)

Comment: Also, what is wrong with *easier* in the first place that would make a different word better? As per an answer, it's a comparative term. For somebody who can do neither, juggling is likely easier than brain surgery. That doesn't mean that juggling is easy.

Comment: Lastly, I don't understand your analogy. If A is "going to Mars" and B is "going to Nipton," in what possible interpretation is going to Mars easier than going to Nipton?

Comment: @JasonBassford I feel easier implies that both are feasible and peace of cake which isn't.  I don't mean this is necessarily true that's why I'm asking here. For your last comment, because of the distance?

Comment: @hbak But Mars is ***much*** farther away than Nipton. How does that greater distance make it easier? As far as I can tell, you've got the definitions of A and B reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you are seeking,  but perhaps "likelier" would work, although it feels awkward. Maybe "more conceivable" is closer to your purpose? Is it possible to share the actual sentence you are working on? It might be easier (and more conceivable) to rearrange it rather than finding this elusive word. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Easier doesn't necessarily mean "easy", just less difficult. But there may be some useful ideas if you look up synonyms of [doable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/doable). For example:

> achievable, conceivable, feasible, practical, ...

You probably need "more" before any of those.

Answer (score 0):

While it’s strictly accurate, I wonder if "likelier" conveys the difficulty aspect? Much depends on the tone of the piece. If it’s lighthearted, there are many possibilities to make a jokey remark, but assuming it’s a bit more serious, perhaps "Both are almost impossible, but A is slightly less impossible than B." Or "Both are formidable challenges, but A slightly less so than B."

Hard to say more without more context.